# Web API: Practices to use different Configuraions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Probably you can give me a hint about good practices: In order to learn a bit more about Web API, I'm trying to create a Web-Service which helps doing some work with the TFS.
It would be very cool, if the Client could select, which TFS he wants to use by passing kindahow an object, which contains the needed data since TFS Service URL etc. But this gives me some troubles:
I created a type called TFSConfiguation, to kindahow pass these information, but this has some drawbacks:

- I can't use Get-Method,s since I'd need to pass this object via Body
- Every method in every Controller needs to get this object passed
- I (think I) can't use Dependency injection, since I need to pass this TFS-Parameter to the Layers behind the Controllers

Other approaches would all hurt the open closed principles I guess, since the Controller really doesn't know which concrete TFS is used.

Is there a good possibility to make such stuff work? If not, what would be the best case for such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't use Get-Method,s since I'd need to pass this object via Body

[The ModelBinder can bind from the URI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

> Every method in every Controller needs to get this object passed

Or you let the user store it in the session with a call, and read it from the session in other calls.

> I (think I) can't use Dependency injection, since I need to pass this TFS-Parameter to the Layers behind the Controllers

Why do you want to inject this?

Comment: Thanks, you and Jamie had the same Idea with the Initial call, which saves to the Session. I guess this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a POST endpoint that accepts a TfsConfiguration object and returns a token, such as a GUID, that is passed to GET endpoints via the URL or a custom header. The flow could be:

1. POST TfsConfiguraton to api/tfstoken, which returns the token
2. Routes which require the token have URLs of the form api/tfstoken/...

Comment: Thanks, seems like the way to go